# ISOTOPE - Missing/Invalid Arguement Get Terms

Tags: php, functions, taxonomy, sort, terms

I am trying to use the isotope plugin for sorting on my taxonomy page and even though I don't know much about how to set it up, I tried using some advice found on here.

> [Wordpress and isotope filtering](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44963/wordpress-and-isotope-filtering)

I did so by taking this code

```
function isotope_categories() {

        $categories = get_categories();

        $html = '<ul class="filters option-set" data-option-key="filter">';
        $html .= '<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All items</a></li>';

        foreach ($categories as $category) {

            $html .= "<li><a href='#filter' data-option-value='.category-{$category->category_nicename}'>{$category->cat_name}</a></li>";   
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

and tried altering it so that it would work with get_terms (custom taxonomy). The code I ended up with is -

```
function isotope_categories() {

        $categories = get_terms();

        $html = '<ul class="filters option-set" data-option-key="filter">';
        $html .= '<li><a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">All items</a></li>';

        foreach ($terms as $term) {

            $html .= "<li><a href='#filter' data-option-value='.category-{$term->name}'>{$term->name}</a></li>";   
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';

        echo $html;
    }
```

However when I use  `<?php isotope_categories() ?>` in my taxonomy page I receive the following errors -

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for get_terms(), called in
>   html/wp-content/themes/lawcademy_theme/functions.php on line 1667 and
>   defined in html/wp-includes/taxonomy.php on line 1165
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   html/wp-content/themes/lawcademy_theme/functions.php on line 1672

How can I fix the code so that I don't get these errors?? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) does not require parameters, by default it will query the post type `post` and the taxonomy `category`. However, [get_terms()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) require a taxonomy parameter.

Also, in the second function, you wrote:

```
 $categories = get_terms();
```

It should have been

```
$terms = get_terms('your_taxonomy');
```

Comment: Thanks!! That fixed the problem. Now I just need to figure out how to get isotopes to work properly so that I can sort posts. TWO MORE QUESTIONS - Is there a way to modify the above code so that only the sub categories of the current page show? And how can I modify it to be a drop down instead of a list?